# why the errorBody disappears retrofit?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

when I do response (). errorBody()? .string () for the first time, I get the error and I can desealize
but when I try to do it a second time this null

```
trip.create(headers = headers, createTripRequest = request)
                .doOnError {
                    if (it is HttpException) {
                        val errorData = it.response().errorBody()?.string()
                        logger.error("Error create_ride with request: $request and error $errorData")
                    }
                }.doOnSuccess {
                    logger.info("End create_ride")
                }.onErrorResumeNext {
                    if (it is HttpException) {
                        val errorData = it.response().errorBody()?.string()// here is null
                }
```

Comment: it is a stream not stored in memory, save it locally -  answer already given here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557988/android-how-to-retain-the-errorbody-in-retrofit-response

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: How to retain the errorBody() in retrofit response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557988/android-how-to-retain-the-errorbody-in-retrofit-response)